# Option to specify default kableExtra Styling in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

Is there a way to set up default `kableExtra` stylings to be applied to **each** table in an `Rmarkdown` document in order to avoid typing the same sytling options over and over again?

In the reprex below, you see that I have to add `kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))`  to each kable I want to produce, so I was wondering whether there is maybe an option which allows to define the default styling?

````
---
title: "Default Kables"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
library(kableExtra)
```


```{r mtcars}
mtcars %>% 
   head() %>% 
   kable() %>% 
   kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive")) 
```

```{r iris}
iris %>% 
   head() %>% 
   kable() %>% 
   kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive")) 
```
````

---

Of course there is a trivial solution to define a helper function like this:

```r
kable <- function(...) {
   knitr::kable(...) %>%
   kable_styling(c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))
}
```

but I was wondering whether there is a dedicated option for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try setting the bootstrap options globally, although you still need to call `kable_styling` repeatedly.

````
---
title: "Default Kables"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)

bs_style <- c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive")

options(kable_styling_bootstrap_options = bs_style)
```

```{r mtcars}
mtcars %>%
  head() %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling()
```
````

---

[image]

---

Comment: Nice. I knew there must have been an option. Out of curisosity, where is this option documented? +1

Comment: I have come to know about this option from the [issue #374](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/374) on the package github repo.

Comment: Lol, once I knew which key word to search for (`kable_styling_bootstrap_options`) I found the very same issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into this and there seems to be a bunch of global options "hidden" in the main functions' source code. Searching for `getOption(*)` in [`knitr/R/table.R`](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/R/table.R) and [`kableExtra/R/kable_styling.R`](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/blob/master/R/kable_styling.R) reveals:

#### `knitr::kable()`

**General**

- `digits` — not specific to `knitr`/`kable`
- `knitr.kable.NA`

**HTML**

- `knitr.table.html.attr`

**LaTeX**

- `knitr.table.vline`
- `knitr.table.toprule`
- `knitr.table.bottomrule`
- `knitr.table.midrule`

#### `kableExtra::kable_styling()`

**General**

- `kable_styling_position` — default: `"center"`
- `kable_styling_font_size`
- `kable_styling_full_width` — default: `TRUE` for HTML and `FALSE` for LaTeX

**HTML**

- `kable_styling_bootstrap_options` — default: `"basic"`

**LaTeX**

- `kable_styling_latex_options` — default: `"basic"`

**Note:** All of them seem to be unset in `options()` by default.

---

To apply `kable_styling()` by default, you can set this option in the YAML header:

```yaml
output:
  html:
    df_print: !expr function(x, ...) kable(x, ...) %>% kableExtra::kable_styling() %>% knit_print()
```